# How to organize your code PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and I am wondering how is the best way to organize your code. I have been trying to do something with a form (form.php) on the client side to talk to a remote server using PHP (testexec.php). I have come down to the issue where my testexec.php needs to access a variable from the form.php file and so now I am wondering if I should just put all my code in form.php so I don't have to call variables from a different php file. How would you guys organize your code in this situation.

form.php

```
<div class="box1">
  <form method="post">
    <label class="col">Up/Dowb</label>
    <span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Down</label> 
</span>
<span class="col">
  <input type="submit" class="button"/>
</span>
  </form>
</div>
<script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".button").click(function(event){
        if ((document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value == '')) {
               alert('Gateway Required!');
        return false;
    }
        else if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 1) {                
               alert('Please Choose Up/Down Value!');
               return false;
        } 
        else {
               //alert('Sucess!');
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url:"testexec.php",
            type: "POST",
                    data: {option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()},
            dataType: "text", 
            success:function(result){
                        $('#div1').html(result)
            }
            });
             return true;
        }
  });
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

testexec.php

```
    $gateway = '';
    $user = 'user';
    $pwd = 'pass';

    function cleanInput($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
     $gateway = cleanInput($_POST['gateway']); //need to get the value of gateway from form.php

      //create the ssh connection
    if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
           ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pwd);  
           if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/tmp/user/testscripts/up.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo '<pre>' . stream_get_contents($stream_out) . '</pre>';

           }

           if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/tmp/user/testscripts/down.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                echo nl2br(stream_get_contents($stream_out));
           }        
     }
} 
?>
```

So now i have to somehow get the value of 'gateway' from my form.php for the following code to work:

```
$gateway = cleanInput($_POST['gateway']);
```

So I was wondering if this is good practive to seperate things like this?

Comment: Look up MVC. MVC is a software architectural pattern. Many of the PHP frameworks are organizing your code naturally when you adhere to MVC principles. There are other architectural patterns to look at to, but when you adopt one you'll see all your code more or less going where it's supposed to go.

Answer (score 0):

I see no advantage in combining the scripts.  There is no magic to $_POST.  It only exists when a script has been the TARGET of a POST, and it doesn't matter if the target is the same script that originally had rendered the form, or a different script.

The only advantage to combining form code into a self-posting, all-in- one version, is when you have iterative error handling.

In that situation, frequently you want to do some server side validation, and if the form doesn't validate, need to send a response with the another form with an error, and usually with the original form elements already filled in, and typically with some visual indication as to which elements caused the problems.

It's much cleaner to have this all in one place, so you aren't reinventing the wheel with the form.

However, moreover, any script is cleaner and easier to read when you separate logic from presentation.

This is a big reason why people use template libraries like smarty or twig, an why every MVC framework comes with some sort of template system.

Even in your case, you could move the form data into it's own seperate script and include it with something like:

```
require_once('form_frm.php');
```

In your case, form.php has no logic whatsoever currently, so I see no major advantage to doing this at the moment.

I would recommend however, that you consider each function you are using, and why you are using it.

Stripslashes() for example, appears to have no value to you in this script, and in fact, stripslashes has had very little use for many years now, as magic_quotes_gpc() was deprecated long ago.

Escaping was a function of SQL database string handling, and due to the issues with different character sets and localization, if you needed to add escape characters, there were better database specific methods like mysql_real_escape_string() which take into account the character set of the client data and database.

At this point in time, most everyone knows that you should be using bind variables for adding string data to SQL queries, which essentially eliminates the need for any escaping of quotes, so there is no need for add slashes or mysql_real_escape_string() whatsoever, and the world is better for it.

If you are not calling addslashes(), why are you calling stripslashes()?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation, quick question, when you say move the form variables to another script, can you give me an example.

Comment: In your case you essentially have already done that because your form.php has no logic in it.  If you wanted to combine the logic into one script, it would still make sense to keep form.php essentially the way that it is now, as a seperate script you would require_once() in the other script.  That way you don't have a bunch of html and javascript in the same script.

Comment: So how would I be able to access 'gateway' in form.php from testexec.php

Comment: This is hypothetical?  If you include/require/require_once, a script, it becomes part of the script that required it, and all variables, functions and objects that are available in the parent are available in the included script.